# PHP : OpenSSL equivilent of mcrypt : MCRYPT_3DES?

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt, 3des

We would like to convert our use of mcrypt to openssl.

Here is our encryption function:

```
mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_3DES,$key,$payload,MCRYPT_ENCRYPT)
```

Here is our decryption function:

```
mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_3DES,$key,$payload,MCRYPT_DECRYPT)
```

What are the openssl_* equivalents of the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `EVP_Encrypt...` functions with `EVP_des_ede3` as the cipher (although you should really be using CBC mode rather than ECB).

https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html#

If it helps, I have a short example for AES written in C++ at https://github.com/shanet/Crypto-Example. Converting it to use triple DES should be trivial.