# AES-Rijndael 128 encryption in Java from PHP

Tags: java, php, aes

I have a piece of code in PHP

```
    function encrypt($data){
$data = "{\"userId\":11,\"email\":\"ssss.bansa11l1989@gmail.com\",\"firstName\":\"Ankit\",\"lastName\":\"Bansal\",\"displayName\":\"banank1989\",\"visitorId\":\"1222222234455\"}";

            $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $this->iv);

            mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $this->iv);
            $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $data);

            mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
            mcrypt_module_close($td);

            return bin2hex($encrypted);
        }
```

Now when I am trying to write the same code in java, it is giving me the different output

```
public String encrypt(String value) {
        try {

            value="{\"userId\":11,\"email\":\"ssss.bansa11l1989@gmail.com\",\"firstName\":\"Ankit\",\"lastName\":\"Bansal\",\"displayName\":\"banank1989\",\"visitorId\":\"1222222234455\"}";
            String initVector = "fedcba9876111111";
            String key = "012345678911111";
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now the issue is both code are giving me the different result for the same provided JSON.

I cant change the PHP code, so I have to change JAVA code.

Comment: Is the same value of initialization vector IV you are using in java as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java and the PHP-code differ:

- In the PHP-code [Zero-Byte-Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding) is used, because this is `mcrypt`'s default padding (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181905/php-mcrypt-encrypt-to-openssl-encrypt-and-openssl-zero-padding-problems)). In contrast, in the Java-code PKCS7-Padding (in Java also called PKCS5) is used. To use Zero-Byte-Padding in the Java-code, first, deactivate PKCS7 padding by replacing `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` with `AES/CBC/NoPadding`. Second, implement manually Zero-Byte-Padding, i.e. add `n` 0-values (with `0 <= n < 16`) to the message's byte-sequence until the length corresponds to an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 Byte).
- In the PHP-code the encrypted data are returned as hex-string. In contrast, in the Java-code the encrypted data are returned Base64-encoded. To change the latter you have to convert the encrypted data into a hex-string, see e.g. [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java).

With these changes, Java- and PHP-code will produce the same result if the same key and the same IV are used (btw the key in the Java-code has a length of 15 byte which results in an `InvalidKeyException (Invalid AES key length: 15 bytes)`).

Note [`mcrypt` is deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) and [Zero-Byte-Padding isn't reliable](http://www.crypto-it.net/eng/theory/padding.html). If you have the choice to change the padding, PKCS7 is preferable.

Comment: Thanks. That is the correct answer. Already fixed it by adding pkcs5 in php code.

Answer (score -1):

You can compare the result run by your code with the result by http://www.maidoupig.cn/encode/aes